# updating data to QTableView from website (intermittently)

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt4, c++14

Updates the QTableView only once as the websites that I am trying to process data from do not auto-update when it has fresh data. I may need to rerun the url to get the latest data as the QTableView updates itself fine when i restart the application. Can someone suggest me a way to do this?. How do i call my slotReadyRead() recursively with some delay. Do i use timers or make it multi threaded or use a while(1)/for(;;) loop? i want to implement a TCP server for Database in the future and think that continuous loops can be messy or be a problem.

```
LogWindow::LogWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent)
{
 ui->setupUi(this);

 manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
 connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
        this, SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
 QNetworkRequest request(web_url);
 reply = manager->get(request);

 connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(slotReadyRead()));
}

void LogWindow::slotReadyRead()
{
    while(reply->bytesAvailable())
    {
       processWebsite1();
       processWebsite2();

       QStandardItem *firstCol = new QStandardItem(rf_ID);
       QStandardItem *secondCol = new QStandardItem(time);

       model->setItem(0,0,firstCol);
       model->setItem(0,1,secondCol);
       ui->logs->setModel(model);
    }  

    emit datachanged(firstCol, secondCol); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a QTimer to fire an action at a defined interval to download the updated data (or the last version if the website was not updated in the meantime).

As you noted, to use a `while(1)` or a `for (;;)` loop is not a good idea.